Is it possible to allow multiple attempts on AWS Cognito Passwordless?
I am working with Cognito Passwordless in AWS for my Ruby on Rails API project. I have created the 3 needed lambdas(DefineAuthChallenge, CreateAuthChallenge and VerifyAuthChallengeResponse) and it works fine but I want to allow the user to have multiple attempts to enter the correct verification code needed to login.
My problem is that if the user fails the first attempt in the second one, after entering the correct verification code, I always get the same message from Cognito("Invalid session for the user").
Digging a little bit more in the problem and checking the logs I realized that the lambda VerifyAuthChallengeResponse is only executed the first time and in the DefineAuthChallenge the second attempt is not beeing registered.
Any help?
My lambdas are something like this.
DefineAuthChallenge
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  puts "Event: #{event.inspect}"
  if event['triggerSource'] == 'DefineAuthChallenge_Authentication'
    session = event.dig('request', 'session') || []
    puts "Session: #{session.inspect}"

    if session.empty?
      # New request to log in
      puts "New request to log in"
      event['response'] = {
        'challengeName' => 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE',
        'issueTokens' => false,
        'failAuthentication' => false
      }
    elsif session.length >= 2 && !session.last['challengeResult']
      # User has incorrectly entered OTP 2 times
      puts "User has incorrectly entered OTP 2 times"
      event['response'] = {
        'issueTokens' => false,
        'failAuthentication' => true
      }
    elsif session.any? { |attempt| attempt['challengeName'] == 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE' && attempt['challengeResult'] }
      # User correctly entered OTP
      puts "User correctly entered OTP"
      event['response'] = {
        'issueTokens' => true,
        'failAuthentication' => false
      }
    else
      # User incorrectly entered OTP - resend code
      puts "User incorrectly entered OTP - resend code"
      event['response'] = {
        'challengeName' => 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE',
        'issueTokens' => false,
        'failAuthentication' => false
      }
    end
  end

  puts "Response: #{event['response'].inspect}"
  event
end

CreateAuthChallenge
require 'aws-sdk-ses'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  puts "Event: #{event.inspect}"

  if event['triggerSource'] == 'CreateAuthChallenge_Authentication'
    code = generate_code
    send_verification_code(event['request']['userAttributes']['email'], code)

    event['response'] = {
      'publicChallengeParameters' => { 'email' => event['request']['userAttributes']['email'] },
      'privateChallengeParameters' => { 'secretLoginCode' => code },
      'challengeMetadata' => 'CODE_DELIVERY'
    }
  end

  puts "Response: #{event['response'].inspect}"
  event
end

def generate_code
  rand(100000..999999).to_s
end

def send_verification_code(email, code)
  ses = Aws::SES::Client.new(region: '*******')
  
  user_status_message = "Welcome!"
  
  ses.send_email({
    destination: { to_addresses: [email] },
    message: {
      body: {
        text: { 
          charset: 'UTF-8', 
          data: "#{user_status_message}\nYour verification code is #{code}" 
        }
      },
      subject: { 
        charset: 'UTF-8', 
        data: 'Your verification code' 
      }
    },
    source: '***@***.***'
  })
end

VerifyAuthChallengeResponse
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  puts "Event: #{event.inspect}"
  
  if event['triggerSource'] == 'VerifyAuthChallengeResponse_Authentication'
    expected_answer = event['request']['privateChallengeParameters']['secretLoginCode']
    provided_answer = event['request']['challengeAnswer']
    
    puts "Expected Answer: #{expected_answer}"
    puts "Provided Answer: #{provided_answer}"
    
    if provided_answer == expected_answer
      event['response']['answerCorrect'] = true
      puts "Answer is correct"
    else
      event['response']['answerCorrect'] = false
      puts "Answer is incorrect"
    end
  end
  
  puts "Response: #{event['response'].inspect}"
  event
end

